# Picasso - how to load vector drawable?

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to load vector drawable using Picasso library

```
    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.project).into(image3a, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

In onError method, getting this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: bitmap == null

When I load image using Glide, it is showing image:

```
 Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.project).into(image3b);
```

My question: How to load vector drawable using Picasso?

Answer (score 11):

Loading Vector drawables is not possible using Picasso. Please check the image for more information

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1109

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

`Picasso.get() .load(R.drawable.ic_my_drawable) .error(R.drawable.ic_my_drawable) .into(imageView)`

workaround - vector drawable asset load if it's set in error(), but not load()
https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1109#issuecomment-161128762